# How to get host address in jsp?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have the following tag which need it to redirect to the following address `localhost/signup`.

If I am in a deep address like `localhost/users/profile/view`and click on this link it goes to 
 `localhost/users/profile/signup`.

How to force it to redirect to `localhost/signup` from any address with any depth without adding `localhost` to the beginning of its address ? is that possible ?

```
   <a href="<s:url action="../signup"/>">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach is to never hardcoded slash prefix (`/signup`) nor relative (`../signup`), but softcode your context root path using `<c:set>`:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

And use it as a prefix for any internal URL

```
<a href="${root}/signup"/>Sign Up</a>
```

Hence you're guaranteed to reference the correct context path even if the depth changes

```
Host/Context Path: http://localhost/blah                 Link: http://localhost/blah/signup
Host/Context Path: http://localhost/mycoolco/secret/blah Link: http://localhost/mycoolco/secret/blah/signup
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying with:

```
<a href="<s:url action="~/signup"/>">Sign Up</a>
```

Above seems to work in ASP.NET and i believe it should work in JSP as well!!

The simple thing, when you put `../SomeMethod` then the server looks up for `SomeMethod` in same directory where the link was clicked.

Comment: thanks, I know about ../ but not sure how to get to root , ~ prefix the signup with itself new address is localhost/users/profile/~/signup

Comment: Please don't confuse Struts2 with JSP. I don't do Struts2, but this works for sure not in JSP.